# Obter valores de propriedades de uma classe

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, classes, reflexão

Tenho os seguintes codigos:

```
private PropertyInfo[] ObterPropriedades(Type classe)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = classe.GetProperties();
    return properties;
}

private string[] ObterValoresPropriedades(Type classe)
{
   List<string> val = new List<string>();
   foreach (var valores in ObterPropriedades(classe))
       val.Add(valores.GetValue(valores,null).ToString());//aqui da o erro
   return val.ToArray();
}
```

ele está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Additional information: Objeto não coincide com o tipo de destino.

Como faço para obter o valor das propriedades?

E tem como passar uma classe como parâmetro pra um método?

o jeito que eu passei a classe como parâmetro `Type classe` e na hora de chamar o metodo:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
ObterValoresPropriedades(p.GetType());
```

é uma forma correta? ou existem outras formas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
private string[] ObterValoresPropriedades(object objeto) {
   var val = new List<string>();
   foreach (var item in objeto.GetType().GetProperties())
       val.Add((item.GetValue(objeto) ?? "").ToString());
   return val.ToArray();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetValueMembers.cs)

Como você vê, precisa pegar o objeto para fazer a avaliação. O tipo (que você chama de classe, mas existem tipos que não são classes) também é necessário mas ele pode ser obtido à partir do objeto.

Aí você chama com:

```
ObterValoresPropriedades(p);
```

Comment: bigown, você postou a resposta quase no mesmo horário que o meu! A semelhança do código parece que um pegou do outro, haha

Comment: Teria que ser o The Flash :P

Comment: Lembrando que `item.GetValue(objeto, null)` pode retornar NullReferenceException caso alguma propriedade tenha valor null, portanto um coalesce seria necessário. `(item.GetValue(objeto, null) ?? "")`

Comment: Dessa forma ele vai popular o array com valores vazios.

Comment: Melhor que dar erro :P claro que dá para evitar isto se ele quiser, basta colocar um `if` para evitar que o `Add` aconteça,

Answer (score 4):

Você está passando só o tipo do Objeto e não o Objeto, eu faria da seguinte maneira:

```
public string[] ObterValoresPropriedades(Object Objeto)
{
    var lista = new List<string>();
    var p = Objeto.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo pop in p)
    {
        var valor = pop.GetValue(Objeto, null);
        if (valor != null)
            lista.Add(valor.ToString());
    }

    return lista.ToArray();
}
```

Pra chamar:

```
ObterValoresPropriedades(p)
```