# Erro ao obter valor de uma propriedade através de reflexão

Tags: c#, reflexão

Estou com problemas na seguinte linha de código:

```
var key = entity.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("id")).GetValue(this, null);
```

Sempre que chega nesta linha ele é lançada uma excepção

> O Objeto não coincide com o tipo de destino.

O método inteiro é este:

```
public void AddOrUpdate(TEntity entity)
{
    var key = entity.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("id")).GetValue(this, null);

    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    if ((int)key == 0)
    {
        _entities.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Comment: Vê se ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44846/obter-valores-de-propriedades-de-uma-classe

Comment: Nao será pelo facto de estar a usar `.GetValue(this, null)`? O `this` nao deveria ser `entity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito corréto de utilizar o GetValue é passar o Objeto, passando this você esta passando a classe em que esta função se encontra, neste contexto.

```
var key = entity.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("id")).GetValue(entity);
```

Desta maneira, e adicione o if(entity == null) antes de criar a variavel key pois pode ocorrer erro de null pointer.

```
 public void AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        {               

        if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        var key = entity.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("id")).GetValue(entity);



         if ((int)key == 0)
            {
                _entities.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

        }
```

Exemplo no [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v14rYE)